# xml to php string variable for child tags

Tags: php, xml

Hi im trying to pass a string from xml file to php variable

xml source : https://airdropalert.com/rssfeed/active

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("active.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object"); 

foreach($xml->entry  as $entry)
 { 
echo $entry->media->icon->imageurl;}
```

Above Code is not getting output. please help

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in your code, use

> imageUrl

not

> imageurl

, tested following code to work:

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents("https://airdropalert.com/rssfeed/active");
$xmldata = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($xmldata->children() as $entry) {
    echo $entry->media->icon->imageUrl;
}
?>
```

Comment: But Shows Error : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: do you have php-xml installed? you need to install  the module so you can use the simplexml_* command. In Debian environment, you can do `sudo apt-get install php-xml`

Comment: Using `$xmldata->children()` will pick up elements which are not the intended ones ( `<id>`, `<link>` etc.)  You should use your original version here - `foreach($xml->entry  as $entry)`